# Como fazer esse foreach para pegar noticias?

Tags: php, api, foreach

Tenho um link que creio que seja uma API, e preciso pegar as noticias (como se fosse um feed) porem já fiz diversos foreach nao consigo associar para trazer o texto que quero dentro do PHP, segue link da api: https://www.caseih.com/latam/pt-br/_layouts/15/CaseIH/ServiceManager.aspx?d=tl-news-release&sort=desc&count=20, alguem pode me ajudar?

PHP:

```
$json_file = file_get_contents("https://www.caseih.com/latam/pt-br/_layouts/15/CaseIH/ServiceManager.aspx?d=tl-news-release&sort=desc&count=20");
$json_output = json_decode($json_file, true);
echo '<pre>';
var_dump( $json_output );

foreach ($json_output as $resultado){
    foreach ($resultado as $items){
        var_dump($items);
    }
}
```

Ai quando tento adicionar ->title ou ->data ele me retorna erro, não sei se é porque não associei errado ou algo do tipo..

Comment: Coloque sua última tentativa na pergunta e descreva o que aconteceu, por favor, para termos noção do que você já fez e não termos que partir do zero.

Comment: Adicionei o codigo..

Comment: Conseguiria me ajudar @AndersonCarlosWoss ?

Comment: A ideia surgiu desse topico mais não é igual, nao aplicou a minha pergunta..

Comment: É igual, sim. Basta adequar ao JSON lido. Você conhece o formato JSON?